# IUI way to display invalid password

Tags: iphone, iui

I'm developing a mobile site using [`IUI`](http://code.google.com/p/iui/).

It's a framework that makes web pages look like `IPhone` dialogs.

I have a tree-like catalog and on a certain level the page asks for a password to proceed.

I'm not quite used to `IPhone` and failed to find a native dialog with a password check that can fail.

What is the "IPhonic" way to handle an invalid password?

Should I display a modal window, an in-page warning in red or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A standard thing here is some kind of [modal alert view](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/ModalViews/ModalViews.html).

IUI presumably implements this already (tho I can't find it from a quick search) but here is how it [looks](http://video.google.com/videosearch?hl=en&client=safari&rls=en&q=iphone%20alert%20view&um=1&ie=UTF-8&sa=N&tab=wv#) (skip to near the end of the video).

Basically a modal alert dialog but with some animation and a spotlight/shine effect. It is largely the animation that makes it feel 'iPhone'.

Comment: Can't find how to do it with `IUI` either, but this does answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

When buying stuff from the AppStore, if the password is invalid you get a modal dialog that states that your password is incorrect and whether you want to retry or cancel.